# Customizing React Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-boilerplate

Hello I am trying to use React boiler plate. offline-first boilerplate, when I remove lines or modules I don't need in the App nothing renders. if you have used react boilerplate before and have success fully customized it or you know of a way this is archivable.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referencing this project (https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json), you could do something like the following

```
npx webpack serve app -config internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js
```

Otherwise you could switch out the node server to leverage nodemon

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server
```